# How to convert months into years and months using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to map one service request object corresponding to another service request object to perform some actions.
First service is having period field in format 2 years and 3 months and second service is having period in format 28 months. I have to convert second service period into 2 years and 3 months. How to convert to this format and assign it to first service variable (firstservicetenure,firsttype)? I referred the below code from stackoverflow and i don't know how to use this in angularjs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function() {
    var data = {
        "firstservicetenure": myservice.details.secondservicetenure,
        "firsttype": myservice.details.secondserviceype
    };
}
function getWords(monthCount) {
    function getPlural(number, word) {
        return number === 1 && word.one || word.other;
    }
    var months = {
      one: 'month',
      other: 'months'
    },
    years = {
       one: 'year',
       other: 'years'
    },
    m = monthCount % 12,
    y = Math.floor(monthCount / 12),
    result = [];
    y && result.push(y + ' ' + getPlural(y, years));
    m && result.push(m + ' ' + getPlural(m, months));
    return result.join(' and ');
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    console.log(getWords(i));
}
```

Comment: You just call the function `getWords(28)`

Comment: `number === 1 && word.one || word.other` might be better written as `number === 1? word.one : word.other` or even `word[number == 1? 'one' : 'other']`.